# Angular 6: [(ngModel)]="variable" vs. ngModel="{{ variable }}"

Tags: angular

The Udemy Angular 6 video I'm watching shows to use the first syntax. However, I'm using WebStorm as my IDE and it does not give any sort of predictive text/suggestion when I use the `[(ngModel)]="variable"` syntax.

If I just type `ng`, it will give me all of the Angular `ng` attributes. If I select `ngModel` it formats the code as `ngModel="{{ variable }}"`.

The code produces the same result regardless of which method I use.

So I was wondering is one method technically correct over the other? I was confused why the video shows to use the `[()]` method, but WebStorm wants me to use the other `ngModel="{{ }}"` method.

Comment: The first option gives 2 way binding, the second does not. If you use the 2nd type to bind to an input, you'll see it doesn't actually update the variable

Comment: @user184994 Ahhh now I see the difference. Thank you! You can make an answer as well.

Comment: You can have a play with https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sy8fa3 to see the difference in action if you like

Comment: @user184994 you should post that as an answer for future readers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is difference, `[]` means one-way data binding, top-down. `[()]` means two-way data binding.

On the other side, `[ngModel]="field"` is equivalent to `ngModel="{{field}}"`.

Furthermore `[(thing)]="field"` is a *banana in a box* syntax sugar.
It is a combination of `[thing]="field"` and `(thingChange)="field = $event"`. `thingChange` here is an [`EventEmitter`](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter).